# Can I use a cell to tell me which column to use on a SUMPRODUCT formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula below:
=SUMPRODUCT('EC(C)DB'!M:M;--(ISNUMBER(MATCH('EC(C)DB'!A:A;$A$33:$A$39;0))) ...

The column which I want to sum (M:M) is variable depending on one Cell. Anyway I can have the formula look at that cell? I can make that cell store M:M or just M, or 13. Nothing like that seems to work.

I could use a series of ifs, with all of the sumproduct possibilities and different columns but that doesnt look very efficient.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `OFFSET` and just set the column argument to the "one Cell"

Comment: and what do I put in that cell? the column? the entire range? not sure I understand.

Comment: If "that cell" is in `P123`, then `=SUMPRODUCT('EC(C)DB'!OFFSET(A:A,0,P123-1);--(ISNUMBER(MATCH('EC(C)DB'!A:A;$A$33:$A$39;0)))`

Comment: Not sure if I made this clear and it might make a difference. EC(C)DB is not the sheet where this formula is placed. So that is giving me an error.
Assuming my formula is on B11 and the cell where I reference the column would be on Q3 should I write the number of the column I want here? What would change on the formula you gave me?

Comment: OH, haha, I missed that 'EC(C)DB' was a sheet name.  Try this `=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET('EC(C)DB'!A:A,0,Q3-1);--(ISNUMBER(MATCH('EC(C)DB'!A:A;$A$33:$A$39;0)))`.  But really, just study the `OFFSET` function and it'll make sense.